# if same laravel sqs jobs calls many times if fails with too many attempts error

Tags: laravel, queue, amazon-sqs, laravel-queue

Dispatch job:

```
for ($i=0;$i<2500;$i++) {
   MyTestJob::dispatch($i);
 }
```

Job class:

```
class MyTestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 1;


    protected $i;
    
    public function __construct( $i)
    {
        $this->i = $i;
    }
    
    public function handle(OrderInProcessRepository $orderInProcessRepository)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have a queue job which needs to be dispatched many times within a very short time, but when I try to run the queue worker, for some jobs it works, and for others it fails:

> Has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have
> previously timed out.

Is there any way to fix this, or it will happen if I call the same job many times within a short period of time?